# Pure Javascript: onClick executes toggle rows -- need image swap

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

First post, long time looker. Stack Overflow ROCKS!

Need some help.  I am primarily a Business Intelligence/Data Warehouse professional.  I need to use a bit of Javascript to create a collapsing row report in a report writing tool where I cannot anticipate the ability to call JQuery (Internal LAN deployment).  Therefore I need pure Javascript.

The premise is I need the report to open with rows only at the Manager/District level but have the ability to open the District clusters to see the assigned Sales Reps and their contribution.

I found code that does this (quite well actually by hiding the repeating District Manager's name) but it uses text objects ("+" and "--") to render the links behind the OnClick event.  I really, really, really, really need to have it show alternating images.

I tried simply modifying these two sections but the code to render the image in the first block does not match the code for the second block, this causes the ternary operation to fail and the images to do not alternate as expected.

1. `lnk.innerHTML =(lnk.innerHTML == "+")?"--":"+";`
2. `var link ='<a href="#" onclick="toggleSection(this);return false;" style="text-decoration: none">+</a>';`

The code below contains the working code with text for onClick action and below a simple onClick that switches the images.  Essentially I need the Folder Icons to be in the first cell of the Manager/District grids.    I forced the working collapse code into the main Javascript block just to save space.

Any help, insight, guidance, electric cattle prod shocks (ouch) would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:  created a CodePen for this to make it easier to see what works right now:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjLvh

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table { empty-cells: show; }
cell {font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11.0pt;color: #000000;}
TD{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 10.5pt;}
TH{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 10.5pt; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript> 
var tbl;
var toggleimage=new Array("http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_open_folder.png","http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_closed_folder.png")

function trim(str){
 return str.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,"");
}

function getParent(el, pTagName) {
 if (el == null) return null;
 else if (el.nodeType == 1 && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == pTagName.toLowerCase()) // Gecko bug, supposed to be uppercase
  return el;
 else
  return getParent(el.parentNode, pTagName);
}

function toggleSection(lnk){

 var td = lnk.parentNode;
 var table = getParent(td,'TABLE');
 var len = table.rows.length;
 var tr = getParent(td, 'tr');
 var rowIndex = tr.rowIndex;
 var rowHead=table.rows[rowIndex].cells[1].innerHTML;

lnk.innerHTML =(lnk.innerHTML == "+")?"--":"+";

 vStyle =(tbl.rows[rowIndex+1].style.display=='none')?'':'none';

 for(var i = rowIndex+1; i < len;i++){
  if (table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML==rowHead){
    table.rows[i].style.display= vStyle;
    table.rows[i].cells[1].style.visibility="hidden";
  }
 }
}

function toggleRows(){
    tables =document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    for(i =0; i<tables.length;i++){
      if(tables[i].className.indexOf("expandable") != -1)
        tbl =tables[i];
    }
    if(typeof tbl=='undefined'){
     alert("Could not find a table of expandable class");
     return;
    }

//assume the first row is headings and the first column is empty
 var len = tbl.rows.length;
var link ='<a href="#" onclick="toggleSection(this);return false;" style="text-decoration: none">+</a>';

 var rowHead = tbl.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;

 for (j=1; j<len;j++){
  //check the value in each row of column 2
  var m = tbl.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML;

if(m!=rowHead || j==1){
   rowHead=m;
   tbl.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML = link;
//   tbl.rows[j].cells[0].style.textAlign="center";
   tbl.rows[j].style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  }
else
   tbl.rows[j].style.display = "none";
}

}
var oldEvt = window.onload;

var preload_image_1=new Image()
var preload_image_2=new Image()
preload_image_1.src=toggleimage[0]
preload_image_2.src=toggleimage[1]
var i_image=0

function testloading() {
    isloaded=true
}

function toggle() {
    if (isloaded) {
        document.togglepicture.src=toggleimage[i_image]
    }
    i_image++
    if (i_image>1) {i_image=0}
}

window.onload = function() { if (oldEvt) oldEvt(); toggleRows(); testloading();}


</SCRIPT>

<TABLE class=expandable width="400px" border="1"  cellspacing="0" frame="box" rules="all" >
  <THEAD>
  <TR>
    <TH  bgColor="#E6E4D4">&nbsp;</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Manager</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Sales Rep</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Amount </TH></TR>
</THEAD>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD><i>Georgia District Reps</i></TD>
    <TD>500000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD>Rex Smtih</TD>
    <TD>350000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD>Alex Anderson</TD>
    <TD>150000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Hobby</TD>
    <TD><i>Texas District Reps</i></TD>
    <TD>630000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Hobby</TD>
    <TD>Bill Smith</TD>
    <TD>410000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Hobby</TD>
    <TD>Simon Wilkes</TD>
    <TD>220000</TD></TR>
</TBODY></font></TABLE>
<br>
<br>
<a href="javascript:toggle()"><img name="togglepicture" src="http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_closed_folder.png" border="0"></a>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgbFx)

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table { empty-cells: show; }
cell {font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11.0pt;color: #000000;}
TD{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 10.5pt;}
TH{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 10.5pt; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript> 
var tbl;
var toggleimage=new Array("http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_open_folder.png","http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_closed_folder.png")

  var closedImgHTML = "<img name=\"togglepicture\" src=\"http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_closed_folder.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"20\">";

  var openImgHTML = "<img name=\"togglepicture\" src=\"http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_open_folder.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"20\">";

function trim(str){
 return str.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,"");
}

function getParent(el, pTagName) {
 if (el == null) return null;
 else if (el.nodeType == 1 && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == pTagName.toLowerCase()) // Gecko bug, supposed to be uppercase
  return el;
 else
  return getParent(el.parentNode, pTagName);
}

function toggleSection(lnk){

 var td = lnk.parentNode;
 var table = getParent(td,'TABLE');
 var len = table.rows.length;
 var tr = getParent(td, 'tr');
 var rowIndex = tr.rowIndex;
 var rowHead=table.rows[rowIndex].cells[1].innerHTML;



lnk.innerHTML =(lnk.innerHTML == openImgHTML)?closedImgHTML:openImgHTML;

 vStyle =(tbl.rows[rowIndex+1].style.display=='none')?'':'none';

 for(var i = rowIndex+1; i < len;i++){
  if (table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML==rowHead){
    table.rows[i].style.display= vStyle;
    table.rows[i].cells[1].style.visibility="hidden";
  }
 }
}

function toggleRows(){
    tables =document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    for(i =0; i<tables.length;i++){
      if(tables[i].className.indexOf("expandable") != -1)
        tbl =tables[i];
    }
    if(typeof tbl=='undefined'){
     alert("Could not find a table of expandable class");
     return;
    }

//assume the first row is headings and the first column is empty
 var len = tbl.rows.length;
var link ='<a href="#" onclick="toggleSection(this);return false;" style="text-decoration: none">'+closedImgHTML+'</a>';

 var rowHead = tbl.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;

 for (j=1; j<len;j++){
  //check the value in each row of column 2
  var m = tbl.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML;

if(m!=rowHead || j==1){
   rowHead=m;
   tbl.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML = link;
//   tbl.rows[j].cells[0].style.textAlign="center";
   tbl.rows[j].style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  }
else
   tbl.rows[j].style.display = "none";
}

}
var oldEvt = window.onload;

var preload_image_1=new Image()
var preload_image_2=new Image()
preload_image_1.src=toggleimage[0]
preload_image_2.src=toggleimage[1]
var i_image=0

function testloading() {
    isloaded=true
}

function toggle() {
    if (isloaded) {
        document.togglepicture.src=toggleimage[i_image]
    }
    i_image++
    if (i_image>1) {i_image=0}
}

window.onload = function() { if (oldEvt) oldEvt(); toggleRows(); testloading();}


</SCRIPT>

<TABLE class=expandable width="400px" border="1"  cellspacing="0" frame="box" rules="all" >
  <THEAD>
  <TR>
    <TH  bgColor="#E6E4D4">&nbsp;</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Manager</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Sales Rep</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Amount </TH></TR>
</THEAD>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD><i>Georgia District Reps</i></TD>
    <TD>500000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD>Rex Smtih</TD>
    <TD>350000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD>Alex Anderson</TD>
    <TD>150000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Hobby</TD>
    <TD><i>Texas District Reps</i></TD>
    <TD>630000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Hobby</TD>
    <TD>Bill Smith</TD>
    <TD>410000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Hobby</TD>
    <TD>Simon Wilkes</TD>
    <TD>220000</TD></TR>
</TBODY></font></TABLE>
<br>
<br>
<a href="javascript:toggle()"></a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice work Zeb.  I struggled to find syntax for the images which would work in both places of the code.  I also was having a hard go at finding a solid way to represent the Images as Variables.  Your final solution shows that I was on the right path.  Thanks for helping push me over the top!  Cheers!

Comment: Zeb,  Quick question.  It seems if I make any changes to my image URL the code freaks out.  Even if I remove the height attribute the toggle fails to work properly.  Any ideas?  I actually need to use a completely different image I was just putting up the one from the internet to help get the code straight.

Comment: Are there any syntax errors in your console? (e.g. in Chrome, press F12 and click Console on your page) If you post the code with actual image urls i'll take a look

Comment: I got around the issue with the syntax but discovered another side effect: IE 8 is not toggling right.  Why does IE always seem to be a problem (tongue in cheek).  In IE once the Open Folder appears, even when clicked next, the Closed Folder does not appear.  ARGGGH!  Chrome and Firefox are 100% on target.

Comment: This probably calls for a new question with the relevant code included

Comment: Sure. I will set up a new question later today.

Comment: Comparing HTML strings to `innerHTML` is risky.  Different browsers may serialize/deserialize the DOM differently.  You'd be better off just looking at the `src` property of that image element.